# OpenAM Relation between sign the SAML Response & Assertion

Tags: saml, openam

we marked "Assertions Signed"  in OpenAM configuration,

and if the SAML response coming from IDP is signed and the SAML assertion is not signed, 
will OpenAM consider this SAML response as a valid SAMLResponse?

note : openam version 13.0.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever since [OPENAM-7055](https://bugster.forgerock.org/jira/browse/OPENAM-7055) has been implemented, AM will consider a signed SAML response as if the assertion itself was signed. The JIRA issue has fix version set to 13.0.0, so this behaviour should be already correct in that version.

Answer (score 0):

> if the SAML response coming from IDP is signed and the SAML assertion is not signed, will OpenAM consider this SAML response as a valid SAMLResponse?

No, as SAML response signing is different from Assertion signing.

Side note: Assertion signing can be negotiated via attributes in the SAML meta data. SAML response signing has to be negotiated out-of-band as the SAML meta data specification has not defined an attribute for it.

Comment: do you have any idea about Signature inheritance inside the  specification for SAML https://docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf @Bernhard Thalmayr

Comment: What do you mean by `Signature inheritance`? I've never come across this term.

Comment: Please check 5.3 Signature Inheritance section in  the specification for SAML docs.oasis-open.org/security/saml/v2.0/saml-core-2.0-os.pdf


and check @Peter Major comment

Comment: So it depends whether the fix for OPENAM-7055 is in your version of OpenAM.